# Cannot get results due to the increase of matrix order

Tags: matrix

There is a proposition:

**If the n-level matrix A satisfies**

$\boldsymbol{A} A^{\prime}=I, \quad|\boldsymbol{A}|=-1$

**then**

$|\boldsymbol{I}+\boldsymbol{A}|=0$

I can use MMA code to give examples of **second-order matrices**:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mA = Array[A, {2, 2}];
mI = IdentityMatrix[2];
detA = Det[mA];
listmA = Flatten[mA];
Reduce[mA . Transpose[mA] == mI && detA == -1, listmA, Reals]
```

or

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mA = Array[A, {2, 2}];
mI = IdentityMatrix[2];
detA = Det[mA]
listmA = Flatten[mA];
sol = FindInstance[mA . Transpose[mA] == mI && detA == -1, listmA, 
  Reals]
Det[mI + mA] /. sol[[1]]
```

> 0

But for **the third or higher order matrix**, the results cannot be obtained, and the program has been running without stopping.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mA = Array[A, {3, 3}];
mI = IdentityMatrix[3];
detA = Det[mA]
listmA = Flatten[mA];
sol = FindInstance[mA . Transpose[mA] == mI && detA == -1, listmA, 
  Reals]
Det[mI + mA] /. sol[[1]]
```

> $Aborted

***How can I improve this code to get results for higher-order matrices?***

Comment: For a start, if you remove the domain restriction `Reals` in `FindInstance` then it returns practically immediately. The answer has real coefficients as well, even though you had not restricted the domain.

Comment: Yes, but the results can only be obtained for matrices of order 3, but not for matrices higher than order 4. @MarcoB

Comment: Work for `n=4`. `n = 4;
mA = Array[A, {n, n}];
mI = IdentityMatrix[n];
detA = Det[mA];
listmA = Flatten[mA];
sol = FindInstance[mA . Transpose[mA] == mI && Det[mA] == -1, 
   listmA];
Det[mI + mA] /. sol[[1]] // Simplify`

Comment: You want to generate examples of such matrices? Or show that the hypotheses imply the proposition?

Comment: I want to generate examples of such matrices A.  @Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: Thank you. I tried n=4, but the resulting matrix contains complex elements. I want to get a real matrix. @cvgmt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know how to get `FindInstance` to generate examples of such matrices, but since $AA^T = 1$ simply means that the matrix is orthogonal, one can use something like

```
randA[n_]:=Orthogonalize[Rationalize[
                 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],{n,n}],1/10]];
randAneg[n_]:=With[{A=randA[n]},If[Det[N[A]]<0,A,randAneg[n]]];
```

It works reasonably quickly for `n` up to about $15$.

**Note.** To check that the determinant of $A + 1$ vanishes, one can pass to numeric entries:

```
With[{n=15},
  Chop[Det[N[randAneg[n]]+IdentityMatrix[n]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you. But I tried, `k = 2; randAneg[k] . Transpose[randAneg[k]]`   cannot get the `IdentityMatrix [2]`. I wonder if my understanding is correct? @user293787

Comment: The problem is that writing `randAneg[2].Transpose[randAneg[2]]` will call `randAneg[2]` twice, so it is not expected to give the identity matrix, just like `RandomReal[]-RandomReal[]` is not expected to give zero! Use `With[{A=randAneg[2]}, A.Transpose[A]] // Simplify` or `With[{a=RandomReal[]}, a-a]` instead.

Comment: Yes, the problem has been solved. Thank you for your help. @user293787